# Terragrunt import existing bigquery resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terragrunt

I want to import an existing google bigquery dataset under my-project-s001, my_dataset

i added in my terragrunt.hcl file the below config

```
terraform {
  source = “./multi”
}


inputs = {
  project_id = “my-project-s001”
  datasets = {
    “my_dataset” = {
      "dataset_id" = “my_dataset”,
      "location" = "EU"
    }
  }
}
```

the module under multi/main.tf

Under multi/main.tf I have

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "datasets" {
  for_each                    = var.datasets
  project                     = var.project_id
  dataset_id                  = can(lookup(each.value, "dataset_id")) == true ? lookup(each.value, "dataset_id") : each.key
  location                    = can(lookup(each.value, "location")) == true ? lookup(each.value, "location") : var.location
}
```

I got to the place where terragrunt.hcl file is there and do the below command

```
terragrunt import "google_bigquery_dataset.datasets[0]" "my-project-s001/my_dataset"
```

The import is successful. However when I see the state file. It  doesn't have the dataset_id.